# Centralized way to force user to logout with a 401 unauthorized in Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am using Swift & Alamofire, and I'd like a universal / single way to force the user to logout in the case of a 401 (Unauthorized) response from our backend.  I was thinking, that in each Alamofire call I could check the response json for the status code, and log the user out.  However, this would result in having to do this check repeatedly in every Alamoafire request / response block.  Is there a way to do this once?  For example, perhaps a way to pass a callback function to the Alamofire.authenticate()?

Comment: Why don't you have an object that incapsulates Alamofire in it? You then just pass request info objects to it, and it does all the network stuff. This way you would have a centralized way for stuff like you're asking

Comment: Okay thanks I will try that approach, maybe using PromiseKit.